# Behavior of primary key in SQLite in Android development

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have my SQLite database cursor which have an ArrayAdapter to populate a Spinner like this:

```
public void loadSpinnerData() {
    List<String> names = db.getAllWalletName();

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item,
            names);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    current_wallet_id = position + times; // times = 1
    double sum = db.getSum(current_wallet_id);
    wallet_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
```

This is the database.

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_WALLET_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_WALLET + " ( "
            + KEY_WALLET_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_WALLET_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL , " + KEY_WALLET_SUM
            + " REAL NOT NULL )";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_WALLET_TABLE);

    String CREATE_TRANSACTION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRANSACTION
            + " ( " + KEY_TRANS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_AMOUNT + " REAL NOT NULL, " + KEY_WALLET_ID
            + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TRANSACTION_TABLE);

}

    public List<String> getAllWalletName() {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "Select " + KEY_WALLET_NAME + " FROM "
            + TABLE_WALLET;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            names.add(c.getString(0));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    c.close();
    db.close();
    return names;
}

    public double getSum(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_WALLET + " WHERE "
            + KEY_WALLET_ID + " = " + id;

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        return c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WALLET_SUM));
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

I also have an `onItemSelected` for this Spinner. I tried to insert the Spinner `int position` into the parameter of `db.getSum`. Everything works fine, but I am afraid of the SQL behavior that I once see in Microsoft Access, that is when a record is deleted, the primary key value is also deleted, and no record will be filled in the hole.

```
ID      Name
1       Dean
2       Sophie
3       Lachland
4       Pete
```

So based on the previous statement, if I delete the first and add another record, it will look like

```
ID      Name
1       Dean
2       Sophie
3       Lachland
5       Roland
```

So how can I fill the 'getSum' parameter, if the ID won't be as exact as display on the Spinner? Or is this just one of the behavior that Microsoft Access have? Can you please suggest any workaround for this? I do think that this is a very common problem, but I can't find the answer after half an hour googling.

Comment: where did you get `id` and pass as parameter for `getsum(int id)` ? Also, I think your problem is that you create an AUTOINCREMENT primary key. Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5198688/719212

Comment: I have just edited my question to include the onItemSelected where I pass my parameter. I also know that this is cause by AUTOINCREMENT, but is there any workaround for this problem? Can I select the record I want without using `getId`? It seems to me that the only thing relevant with the `ArrayAdapter` is the `position`. I don't understand what that `View` is for, and I don't know how to make use of it for selecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need asoiciate the Spinner position  With an array Of Ids :

Change:

```
public List<String> getAllWalletName() {
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

String selectQuery = "Select " + KEY_WALLET_NAME + " FROM "
        + TABLE_WALLET;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        names.add(c.getString(0));


    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

TO:

```
public List<mObjectNames> getAllWalletName() {
List<mObjectNames> names = new ArrayList<mObjectNames>();



SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

String selectQuery = "Select * FROM "+ TABLE_WALLET;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
mObjectNames mUnicobjectName = cursorToobjectName(c);
names.add(mUnicobjectName);

    } while (c.moveToNext());
}

private mObjectNames cursorToobjectName(Cursor cursor){
mObjectNames objectName = new mObjectNames();

objectName.setKEY_WALLET_ID(c.getLong(0));
objectName.setKEY_WALLET_NAME(c.getString(1));


return objectName;
}
```

Class mObjectNames :

```
public class mObjectNames {

long KEY_WALLET_ID;
String KEY_WALLET_NAME; 
String KEY_WALLET_SUM; // i am not sure if  REAL NOT NULL , is an String, integer...

private void setKEY_WALLET_ID(long KEY_WALLET_ID){
this.KEY_WALLET_ID = KEY_WALLET_ID;
}

private long getKEY_WALLET_ID(){
return KEY_WALLET_NAME;
}

private void setKEY_WALLET_NAME(String KEY_WALLET_NAME){
this.KEY_WALLET_NAME = KEY_WALLET_NAME;
}

private String getKEY_WALLET_NAME(){
return KEY_WALLET_ID;
}


}
```

List all the Persons:

```
List<mObjectNames> names = db.getAllWalletName();

// Convert Object to Array for show in ArrayAdapter needs the conversion.

String arrayOfValues [] = new String[names.size()]; 

for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
arrayOfValues[i] = names.get(i).getKEY_WALLET_NAME;

}
```

And:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

// int position, matches with the position in the List 'names'
String id = names.get(position).getKEY_WALLET_NAME;
long id= names. get(position).getKEY_WALLET_ID
// With that, dont care the Id, or The position.

}
```

Comment: This line `mObjectNames objectName = new mObjectNames()` should move into do... while loop, and add this line `names.add(objectName);` after getting data for objectName.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your approach is not correct. Your id parameter depends on spinner's position while it shouldn't:

```
current_wallet_id = position + times; // times = 1
```

So when primary id doesn't have order, your id is wrong.
**Solution**:
Try to create a custom adapter which has at least two fields: id & name, which wrapped into an object.You can refer to [this](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107)
It looks like this:

```
  private class Wallet{
     int id;
     int name;
  }
```

And your get all wallet method:

```
public List<Wallet> getAllWalletName() {
    // select id and name, then pass to Wallet object
}
```

Finally, in your adapter:

```
 // do your own to create custom adapter
 CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter();

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
    Wallet item  = adapter .get(position);
    double sum = db.getSum(item.id );
    wallet_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
}
```

Hope this can help